# Configuring user uploaded A1 certificates on Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, wcf, asp.net-core, x509certificate2

I have a very specific situation:

A website that consumes endpoints of a WCF web service using TSL handshake. Many users can register on this website, upload their A1 certificates and consume the web service's endpoints through this system.

Locally, on Windows, hosted by IIS, it worked great, when the user uploads his certificate, it is saved on the database as a blob, when I need to talk to the web service I do the following:

```cs
certificate = new X509Certificate2(company.Certificate.File, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

// the SendFileServiceClient object is an auto-generated object, created when the WCF web service was registered
var sendFile = new SendFileServiceClient();

sendFile.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;

await sendFile.OpenAsync();
answer = await sendFile.SendFileAsync(XElement.Parse(xmlFile));
await sendFile.CloseAsync();
```

But the problem comes when I containerize the application. With docker it doesn't work, I can upload my certificate, the blob is created ont the DB, I can even retrieve it and create the X509Certificate2 object (all the information of the certificate is there when I inspect it while debugging), but, at the `answer =` line, I get the following:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'webservices.foo.bar'

Here's the stack trace:

```cs
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The base for my Docker image is:
`FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime`

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here? Is it even possible to do what I need with a docker image?

Comment: It'll probably work if you're `ContainerAdministrator`.  I believe that the normal container user doesn't have a profile loaded... maybe there's a way to get it to load a user profile?

Comment: I'll search about this approach, if I find anything, will return here. Thanks for the tip!